# How do I use win32gui and win32api to locate and move a window in windows, using python

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32gui, pyautogui

This issue really arises from me not understanding what I have to pass to win32gui.EnumWindows()

http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__EnumWindows_meth.html

The short version of what Im trying to accomplish:

1. Detect a window that may be on any of 4 different monitors (my remote desktop window, not anything actually running on the remote desktop)
2. Move the window to a certain monitor (I can find the monitor HANDLE already)
3. Maximize the window

I would like to accomplish this via win32gui and win32api

I do however have a possible other method:
If anyone knows how to make pyautogui screenshot functions observe anything other than the primary display, then it would be possible to

Use pyautogui to detect the remote desktop window header (always the same, but could appear on 4 monitors, then click on it and drag to proper monitor and maximize with pyautogui.

and a third method:

Use pygetwindow to locate and bring to focus the remote desktop window, then use win32api to move that to the proper monitor.  I would need a way to use win32 to get the HANDLE of the focused window.

EDIT: I was able to get WHAT I THOUGHT was the right handle using

`pygetwindow.getAllTitles()` to find the title of the remote desktop program, then using `pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('MyRemoteDesktopName - Remote Desktop Connection')` since 'MyRemoteDesktopName - Remote Desktop Connection' was listed as the title before.  This provided me with a handle that I used 
`win32gui.MoveWindow(197160, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, True)` to move the window to my original screen.  HOWEVER, the remote desktop bar did not move,a nd the screen, while it now fit, did not rescale the way dragging the bar to another window would have.  Each of my monitors has a different size and resolution and my remote desktop auto scales to match whatever I drag the bar to.  But when I use wMoveWindow, it disconnects from that bar

Comment: Do you use [extend displays](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4340331/windows-10-set-up-dual-monitors) to set your 4 different monitors?

Comment: Now that you have the certain window handle, can't you use the `MoveWindow` function to move the window to a specific monitor? You can try  `EnumDisplayMonitors` + `GetMonitorInfo` which should give you the coordinates of each monitor, then call `SetWindowPos` to move it to whichever you want.

Comment: move window actually moves the display, but does not have it perform the same functions.  Hard to show you what I mean without recording a video and I cant because of my workspace.  MoveWindow moves the display of the window, but not its position it seems.  It does not cause the vm to recognize the new screen resolution and scale as needed.  Imagine if you used move window on chrome and it left the address bar and minimize maximize close bar at the top of monitor 3, but moved the image of what you were viewing to monitor 1, also, yes, I have extend displays

Comment: As you said, this is really hard to understand because I have not been able to reproduce your problem. If it's convenient, maybe you can repost a post about this problem with detailed screenshots or code information. Current issues are widespread.

Comment: ill do a series of screenshots before and after certain functions are called, particularly move window.  Might be a few days tho, my work environment has changed to home for the time being.

Comment: If you updated, please let me know.